# what one should use for open source in memory java caching?

Tags: caching, in-memory, hazelcast

What should one use (open source) for in memory Java caching when the caching is used for stock market project? I used hazelcast but it consumes too much memory.

Comment: just wondering - which version of hazelcast are you using?  Can you share your config for your maps?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some good alternatives out there (I have never worked with hazelcast). [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) is a very good option.

Though not very robust but yes a good foundation is surely the `Guava` library. Or you can simple build a LRU cache yourself.

If memory is concern, you can use a `ConcurrentHashMap` which will map key to its `cached` value. But you can wrap the `cached` value with a [Weak Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html). Hence under higher load, it will make sure that your application always has sufficient memory